# Selectively load data using Oracle 11g r2 External Table Preprocessor

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, etl, import

I am using the Preprocessor feature in Oracle 11g r2 to load several data files in a table. However, the raw files seem to have certain rows that shouldn't be imported with the rest. For example:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
 A       1       2       3
 A       2       3       4
 B       ab      bc      cd
```

So, I want to only load the rows with col1 = 'A' and load the rows with col1 = 'B' into another table. How can I do this inside the processor?

Answer (score 0):

If this is how the data looks like then you can just have an external table ext_a. Then do "insert into table_a select * from ext_a where col1 = 'A'". And similar op for B.

I am not sure where your preprocessor comes in here. Preprocessor is used usually before data source is made available for external table to read from. Are we missing any details here? –

You can add a 'LOAD WHEN' condition but then you have to have multiple external tables (one for each condition) or keep doing ALTER TABLE to switch the condition. If you keep a single table, changing INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM is much much easier to manage dynamically IMHO. Hence my recommendation of having a single external table and changing SELECT as needed. - https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/26044